# Copy and Paste data into new worksheet until certain year [VBA]

Tags: vba

I have 3 columns of data with the first column being dates in m/dd/yyyy format and the other two columns not relevant to the question. What I want to do is write  code for a command box or macro that will copy the entire range of date only up to a certain year, 1996 (the dates in column A are in chronological order from 1986 - 2017). Then I would like this portion of the data in the range to be pasted into another worksheet in the workbook. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every item in the column while the  year is less then 1996 to find the last row-index and then select/copy the entire range.

For example:

```
Sub sample()
Dim idx As Integer

    idx = 1
    Do While Year(Cells(idx, 1).Value) < 1996
        idx = idx + 1
    Loop

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(idx - 1, 3)).Copy 
    Sheets("name of worksheet").Range("first cell of range you'd like to paste into").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Julij, this makes sense to me. However, when I click the CommandButton, I receive a Run-time error '6': Overflow with the Debugger highlighting the "idx = idx +1" section of the code. ANy idea what the issue may be?

Comment: hi. just make sure that the dates are in the first column (e.g. column A).

Comment: Thanks so much, the issue was with alignment as you suggested, the entire 3-column range of data actually began in cell B3 rather than A1, I was able to adjust. If you don't mind me asking another question, how would you go about altering this code such that a specific "target" year can be inputted and the code would copy and paste the data just as before except this time, up to the "target year" that can be changed in the code, rather than specifically up to year 1996, if that makes sense. Thanks again!